# How to use Flux pattern in client side(browser)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I am working on a website with React.js and asp.net mvc 4, I am planning to use Flux as my front-end architecture, but I met some problems and was very confused about the use of Flux:

In the beginning,I thought Flux would be a perfect front-end architecture in my website,but after I read a lot of articles about Flux, I find that they are nearly all with NodeJs,even the demos from facebook team,that means they all do the rendering stuffs of React.js/Flux code in server side,right? but How can I use Flux in the client side ,I mean in the user's browser?

I am very confused,am I wrong if I treat react.js/flux as a client side solution?If I am not wrong, but why they all use them with NodeJs and ES6(like facebook Dispatcher.js), That's ok in server side,but what about client side ? most of user broswers don't support ES6. I tried using Babel to convert Dispatcher.js from ES6 to ES5,but the es5 version had some errors and didn't work.

And I also found some implements of Flux that claim to support client side,like fluxxor,but I don't have a chance to try it before I write this post,because I am too confused.

I hope someone can help me to figure out these problems.

*ps. Sorry for my english,if you don't understand my words,pls let me know , I will explain it.*

Comment: I found a project on github:[react-flux-js-lib](https://github.com/rbtech/react-flux-js-lib), it's  a client-side library for the React Flux architecture, I try it and works well,I think it's just what I want and going to use it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want :

> $ bower install flux

Then you could do something like this (if using require.js):

```
require(
    ['bower_components/flux/dist/Flux'], 
    function(
        Flux ) 
{

    var dispatcher = new Flux.Dispatcher();

    dispatcher.register(function(payload) { 

        if (payload.actionType='test') {
            console.log('i got a ', payload); 
        }

    });

    dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: 'test',
        otherData: { foo: 'bar' }
    });

});
```

*(This answer uses : https://bower.io/, https://libraries.io/bower/flux, http://requirejs.org/)*

Answer (score 0):

React is a client side library. You can serve a React App with virtual any backend language. The reason a lot of examples are with node is because it is easy and fast to set up.

You should try this tutorial:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

It is pretty straight forward and doesn't require node.
Also maybe you should try starting to serve the React app statically at the beginning to better understand React itself.

ES6 works in Browsers thanks to [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/jsx/). If you believe you have any trouble with Babel, you might want to first play around with it's REPL to get a feeling for it: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that the code can run on the client and server (universal js, used to be called isomorphic javascript (though it goes a little further then that with serverside rendering etc..),

There are many flux implementations reflux is the most promising at this point , im using martyjs (but they stopped the development, it will be taken over by alt) but even for the flux architecture, u just get the dispatcher / event emitter and some ideas :D,

Shorty said u can install the npm packages (flux, react , babel) etc, but u need something like http://browserify.org/(with reactify) or Webpack, to run them in the browser. U don't need to run them on a node js "after its bundled", webpack/browserify will bundle the code so it can used within the browser independently

https://github.com/christianalfoni/flux-react-boilerplate/ <-- ther are some boilerplate, that provide some nice guide on how to bundle the code.